# Wordpress IP Server Change

Tags: php, wordpress, web, server

I have a problem with my wordpress site. Recently the IP Address server of my wordpress site has changed and now the site just show black and white background color. widget, menu, plugin and others just gone. i can still access wp-admin page, and post,page, media is still there but i can't access my custom plugin. i have tried this [WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) but still did not solve my issue.

is there any file that have to re-configure with new ip address ? or am i missing something ? i'll really appreciate any help, Thanks in Advance !

Comment: How were you accessing the site? Was it just using an IP address or a domain? Did the website URL change at all? Can you share a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your urls addresses in db in table 'wp_options', line 'siteurl' and 'home' .. And also you can change urls in admin panel

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings